# How to move the updated data to the new row(below the old data) by keeping the old data constant with the help of Userform?

Tags: vba, excel

I need some help with updating the data in the Excelsheet using Userform. I was successful in searching the data with a unique Id by creating a search button on the userform and updating the data.

But my problem is after I modify the data w.r.t unique ID it should get updated in my worksheet in a new row below the old data with the same unique id selected.

For more clarity i have attached a sample Image how it should look.

Below is my Code which I tried to create a new row but not able to Keep the old data unchanged.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Set WB = Workbooks.Open("C:\Desktop\Process.xlsx")
    Set ssheet = WB.Worksheets("Process1")
    Dim totalrow As Long
    totalrow = ssheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    For currentrow = 2 To totalrow
        If Trim(tbsno) = Trim(Cells(currentrow, 1)) Then
            tbaxalant = Cells(currentrow, 2)
            tbrequest = Cells(currentrow, 3)
        End If
    Next currentrow
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Dim WB As Workbook
    Set WB = Workbooks.Open("C:\Desktop\Process.xlsx")
    Set ssheet = WB.Worksheets("Process1")
ssheet.Range("A4").Select
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=x1Down
    Dim fvalue As Range
    Set fvalue = ssheet.Range("A:A").Find(What:=Me.tbsno.Value, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    fvalue.Value = Me.tbsno
    fvalue.Offset(0, 1).Value = Me.tbaxalant
    fvalue.Offset(0, 2).Value = Me.tbrequest

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: just as a note: `x1Down` should be `xlDown`

Comment: Thank you. I have changed this and I can only get a new row above the old row but the updation is happening only in the old row and new row is just empty.